# Why hasn't the Senate's "Nuclear Option" been invoked?

Tags: united-states, senate-rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In the U.S., why does the majority party in a new Senate session always approve the filibuster rule?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/112/in-the-u-s-why-does-the-majority-party-in-a-new-senate-session-always-approve)

I have heard recently that there is (likely) a parliamentary procedure by which the Senate's cloture rules could be amended by a simple majority. Since the Civil Rights era, filibustering has been regarded as an obstacle to major legislation that the majority party wants passed. For what reason has this option not been invoked yet?

Comment: I'm having a strong feeling of Deja Vu. Must be a glitch in the Stack Exchange Matrix.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Didn't see it come up under the list of similar questions